# Git: deleted filed in ours but not in theirs prevent "git checkout --ours ." from working

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I have fetch content from a remote repository.
When I try to do `git merge` I get the following message:

`CONFLICT (modify/delete): mimic_pipeline_tools/data_cleaning_scripts/dc.log deleted in HEAD and modified in refs/remotes/origin/master.  Version refs/remotes/origin/master of mimic_pipeline_tools/data_cleaning_scripts/dc.log left in tree.`

As I want to keep my version of all files I tried `git checkout --ours .` but it shows the following error: `error: path 'mimic_pipeline_tools/data_cleaning_scripts/dc.log' does not have our version`

Thank you very much for any help !

Answer (score 0):

You have deleted the file and committed the deleting in your branch.  Someone else made changes to the file and committed them to `master`.  So when you do a `git merge`, you get the first message.  The conflict is because you deleted the file and then someone else edited it, so git can't figure out what to do and it is very cautious about making decisions on changes.
If you had run `git merge-tool`, git would have asked if you want to keep the file deleted or use the modified file from `master`

The second error is because you are trying to checkout the file but you want to use what you have on your branch.  The file was deleted so git has no file to checkout and is telling you so.

You will have difficulty in merging to/from master with this conflict (your branch has the file deleted, while master has modifications made to it).  So you do want to resolve this.